# Cloud Dataflow:Reading entire json array file from Cloud Storage and create a PCollection of json object

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a json array file with content as below

```
[ {  
  "MemberId" : "1234",  
  "Date" : "2017-07-03",  
  "Interactions" : [ {  
    "Number" : "1327",  
    "DwellTime" : "00:03:05"    
  } ]  
}, {  
  "MemberId" : "5678",  
  "Date" : "2017-07-03",  
  "Interactions" : [ {  
    "Number" : "1172",  
    "DwellTime" : "00:01:26"  
  } ]  
} ]
```

I wanted to create a PCollection of Java Object mapped to each Json present in Json array

Answer (score 2):

JSON formatted like this (records spread over multiple lines instead of one per line) is hard for a data processing tool like beam/dataflow to process in parallel - from a random point in the file, you cannot be sure where the next record begins. You *can* do it by reading from the beginning of the file, but then you're not really reading in parallel.

If it's possible, reformatting it so that it's one record per line would let you use something like TextIO to read in the file.

If not, you'll need to read the file in one go.

I would suggest a couple possible approaches:

#### Write a ParDo that reads from the file using the gcs API

This is pretty straight forward. You'll do all the reading in one ParDo and you'll need to implement the connection code inside of that pardo. Inside the pardo you would write the same code you would as if you're reading the file in a normal java program. The pardo will emit each java object as a record.

#### Implement a filebasedsource

File based sources will work - when the fileOrPatternSpec is "gs://..." it knows how to read from GCS. You'll need to make sure to set fileMetadata.isReadSeekEfficient to false so that it won't try to split the file. I haven't tried it, but I believe the correct way to do that is to set it inside of the single file constructor of FBS (ie, your class's override of FileBaseSource(MetaData, long, long)

TextSource/XmlSource (and their accompanying wrappers TextIO/XmlIO) are examples of this, except that they try to implement splitting - yours will be much simpler since it won't.

Comment: In addition to what Stephen mentioned, you can prevent splitting by overriding the isSplittable() method.  - https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TFRecordIO.java#L481